# Cross-region read replica cluster encryption not supported for engine aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I encounter the following error when I try to create a cross-region read replica of my Mysql cluster though AWS console.

```
Cross-region read replica cluster encryption not supported for engine aurora 
(Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: b98941a4-9bac-401e-8a59-9b5ececa601e; Proxy: null)
```

I followed the Amazon guide here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.html but still landed at the error above.

Comment: Since you are following the tutorial, can you specify exactly at what step it fails. Also have you made any changes yourself to the procedure described?

Comment: Not at all. This happens at the final point of creation or clicking on the `Create` button after selecting and filling all the fields required.

Comment: Have you enabled binlog as indicated in the docs?

Comment: Yes. Already changed the option to 'MIXED' like the docs stated